# Two stylesheets acting on one element

Tags: child-theme, css

I am trying to style one element with `max-width` and I was having problems. I discovered that the child theme stylesheet was being augmented by the original stylesheet with `width` at the same time. [image]

What gives? I could go in and remove the line from the parent theme but I worry about future-proofness?!?

Comment: Please confirm us, [1] the `custom.css`'s path are different, and [2] In your `functions.php` (in both parent and/or child) there is no repeat of stylesheet calling like: `wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwelve-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );`. In the case of #2 a stylesheet call in `header.php` repeats stylesheet in a theme.

Comment: PS, Kudos for worrying about future-proofing! (IMO, that is a highly over looked aspect by most WP developers)

Comment: @MayeenulIslam There was an if_statement in the parent theme header. I only changed one of the `get_template_directory_uri();`statements to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri();`. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, `!important` it out!

In the child, change it to `max-width:769px !important;`. That will force the page to be rendered with that style.

I have a feeling the parent theme is using `@import` to get *custom.css* (although I cant verify that). That could be screwing with things.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I am using Gridly, which is responsive but I want to make it even more responsive. I created a child theme. When I added the `header.php` file to my child theme directory I only changed one line of the if_statement that determines what css file to call. In the child theme, I have to call a css file with `get_stylesheet_directory_uri();` . I wanted to use the `custom.css` file and that was the only line of the if statement that I changed. There were three more stylesheets to choose from. To solve that, I went back into my child theme header.php and searched and replaced all `get_template_directory_uri();` that call css files with `get_stylesheet_directory_uri();`.

Gridly theme doesn't use style.css the same way as most WordPress themes. There are no styles in the style.css, it merely exists. It is not a WordPress sanctioned theme that you can download from WordPress. I heard about it from Lynda.com. It calls stylesheets from an if_statement in the header and then links to specific stylesheets, i.e. dark.css, light.css, etc. I am not sure if this functionality is what keeps it out of the WordPress Theme directory, but it works and I like the simplicity and masonry effects.